# i have created a contacts page using react-redux but on clicking on ./contacts/user it is not displaying the content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I was trying to make a contact app on which contact page would have some contact entries and on clicking them a particular contact gets open(as expected).
But, in my case on clicking the contact it is not showing anything except navbar.

**THIS IS MY INDEX.JS FILE (created store)**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/rootReducer";
import { legacy_createStore as createStore } from "redux";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**THIS IS MY APP.JS FILE**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./componenets/Home";
import Navbar from "./componenets/Navbar";
import About from "./componenets/About";
import Contact from "./componenets/Contact";
import Card from "./componenets/Card";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="/card/:user" element={<Card />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
export default App;
```

**THIS IS MY CARD.JS FILE**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Card extends React.Component {
  onButtonClick = () => {
    this.props.deleteCard(this.props.card.id);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { title, body } = this.props.card;
    return (
      <div
        className="ui raised very padded text container segment"
        style={{ marginTop: "80px" }}
      >
        <h3 className="ui header">{title}</h3>
        <p>{body}</p>
        <button
          className="ui primary right floated button"
          onClick={this.onButtonClick}
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  let title = ownProps.match.params.user;
  console.log("state:", state); // Check state structure
  console.log("ownProps:", ownProps); // Check ownProps
  return {
    card: state.cards.find((card) => card.title === title),
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    deleteCard: (id) => {
      dispatch({ type: "deleteCard", id: id });
    },
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Card);
```

**THIS IS MY CONTACT.JS FILE**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const Contact = ({ cards }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {cards.map((card) => {
        return (
          <div
            className="ui raised very padded text container segment"
            style={{ marginTop: "80px" }}
            key={card.id}
          >
            <Link to={`/${card.title}`} className="ui header">
              {card.title}
            </Link>
            <p>{card.body}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    cards: state.cards,
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Contact);
```

**THIS IS MY ROOTREDUCER FILE**

```
const initialState = {
  cards: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Alex",
      body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ajdbabwdj adadawdawda adaw , jwajw ad awd a",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Wilma",
      body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ajdbabwdj adadawdawda adaw , jwajw ad awd a",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "John",
      body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ajdbabwdj adadawdawda adaw , jwajw ad awd a",
    },
  ],
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  return state;
};
export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

The contact card is linking to `` to={`/${card.title}`} ``, which based on the  cards state you provided means the link targets are `"/Alex"`, `"/Wilma"`, `"/John"`, etc. There are no routes rendering paths that match these.

I suspect you meant to link to the `"/card/:user"` route. Update the link target in `Contact` to the correct target route path, e.g. `` to={`/card/${card.title}`} ``.

Example:

```
const Contact = ({ cards }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {cards.map((card) => (
        <div
          className="ui raised very padded text container segment"
          style={{ marginTop: "80px" }}
          key={card.id}
        >
          <Link to={`/card/${card.title}`} className="ui header">
            {card.title}
          </Link>
          <p>{card.body}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

React-Router v6 also did away with Route props, so there is no defined `props.match.params` to access the `user` path param of `"/card/:user"`. Convert `Card` to a function component so it can use the `useParams` hook.

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Card = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { user } = useParams();
  const card = useSelector(state => state.cards.find((card) => card.title === user));

  const onButtonClick = () => {
    if (card) {
      dispatch({ type: "deleteCard", id: card.id });
    }
  };

  const { title, body } = card || {};
  return (
    <div
      className="ui raised very padded text container segment"
      style={{ marginTop: "80px" }}
    >
      <h3 className="ui header">{title}</h3>
      <p>{body}</p>
      <button
        className="ui primary right floated button"
        onClick={onButtonClick}
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```